# Python fastest way to gets element's array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm looking for the fastest way to get elements into an array. Suppose we have a Class like this:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.let = a
        self.num = b
```

Now suppose we have an array of tests :

```
test1 = test("a", "1")
test2 = test("b", "2")
test3 = test("c", "3")
vec = [ test1, test2 , test3]
```

I would like the result to be something like this:

```
newest = []
for t in vec:
   if(t.let == "a" or t.num == "3")
      newest.append(t)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html). I also modified your example, but could not update the question as another edit is pending.

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.let = a
        self.num = b

test1= test("a","1")
test2= test("b","2")
test3= test("c","3")

vec = [ test1, test2 , test3]

newest = [t for t in vec if( t.let == "a" or t.num == "3")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, let='', num=''):
        self.let = let
        self.num = num

test1 = test('a', '1')
test2 = test('b', '2')
test3 = test('c', '3')

vec = [test1, test2, test3]

newest = [i for i in vec if i.let == 'a' or i.num == '3']

newest_args = [(i.let, i.num) for i in newest]
# [('a', '1'), ('c', '3')]
```